# TypeScript type to string literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Need find a way to represent type as string literal, just as if it were called from regular code. For example:

```
interface User {
  name: string
  post: {
    title: string
  }
}

const literalName: Literal<User> = 'name'
const literalPostTitle: Literal<User> = 'post.title'
```

First level easily accessed with

```
type Literal<T> = `${keyof T}`
```

But I don't know how to go deeper in nested structures

Comment: You want either `Paths` or `Leaves` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mL4a2m)